# Swift ругается на операцию деления в Numeric

Tags: swift

Задача создать универсальную функцию по операциям с числами типа **Int** и **Double**.
Делаю вот таким образом, но на операцию деления получаю ошибку.

Может есть другие способы?

```
func operation<T:Numeric>(_ op: String, leftValue: T, rightValue: T) -> T {
        switch op {
            case "+": return leftValue + rightValue
            case "-": return leftValue - rightValue
            case "*": return leftValue * rightValue
            case "/": return leftValue / rightValue
        default:
            return 0
        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: func operation<T:FloatingPoint> не подойдет?

Comment: Нет. Проблема в том, что мне как Int нужен так и Double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете для `Int` сделать отдельную реализацию. При этом числа всех других типов будут использовать реализацию для `FloatingPoint`, в том числе и если передать для `leftValue` и `rightValue` числа разных типов

```
func operation<T:FloatingPoint>(_ op: String, leftValue: T, rightValue: T) -> T {
    switch op {
    case "+": return leftValue + rightValue
    case "-": return leftValue - rightValue
    case "*": return leftValue * rightValue
    case "/": return leftValue / rightValue
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func operation<T:SignedInteger>(_ op: String, leftValue: T, rightValue: T) -> T {
    switch op {
    case "+": return leftValue + rightValue
    case "-": return leftValue - rightValue
    case "*": return leftValue * rightValue
    case "/": return leftValue / rightValue
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```